# How to create a persistent live on a file (disk image)?

Tags: live-usb, persistence, disk-image, mkusb

I created a personnalized ubuntustudio iso with cubic (it is smaller than the official).

And i would like to write a persistent live in a file less than 4G (audio-ubuntustudio.img)

In order to be able to clone the disk image to USB keys using dd or rufus.exe even if they are greater than 4GB.

I've tried with mkusb but it doesn't want to write to disk image.

Do you know an mkusb option or another tool to do that ?

Comment: I use Disks to create image files of my bootable USB's. It comes with Ubuntu. Once Disks is open, click on your drive and then on the three lines upper right. Once your image is created you can use mkusb to clone to USB's

Comment: When you have a persistent live system in a USB pendrive (made with mkusb and tweaked by you afterwards) you can clone from the pendrive to an image file `file.img` or xz-compressed image file `file.img.xz`. You can do this cloning with for example **Disks** (`gnome-disks`). From that file **`mkusb`** can clone into other USB pendrives (or memory cards or SSDs with the same size or bigger) and get working persistent live drives. This is how I created the systems described at [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent#Compressed_image_file_with_a_persistent_live_system).

Comment: The problem i'm trying to solve is that my usb key give me an image too large. I want to limit the image to a certain size. I don't have a usb key of that size. So what i would like to do is to create a raw disk file image and tell to mkusb it is a usb drive ...

Comment: I see the problem. There is no way to tell mkusb directly. It should work, if you use a virtual machine with a virtual disk of the desired size (can be done with VirtualBox), but I have not used that method. It should also work to let mkusb fill your USB pendrive, and after that use gparted to modify the size of the partitions near the tail end of the drive and/or move one of them, partition #1 (usbdata) and partition #5 (the partition for persistence), and them clone only the used part of the drive.

Comment: Thanks @sudodus, i created a file of the target size, i created a virtual disk of that file, attached it to a machine configuration as usb storage and then execute mkusb using virtualbox.

Comment: I'm glad that you found a method that works :-)

Answer (score 1):

Install virtualbox:

```
sudo apt install virtualbox
```

Start by creating a file of the desired size:

```
fallocate -l 3900M my-virtual-usb-stick.img
```

start virtualbox:

```
sudo virtualbox
```

Create a virtual machine with a virtual disk on which you will install Linux and mkusb using the graphical interface. Or start an iso image with mkusb built-in.

Attach (with virtualbox GUI) to that virtual machine a usb storage disk my-virtual-usb-stick.vmdk created with the following command in a terminal (CTRL+ALT+t):

```
sudo VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk \
     -filename ./my-virtual-usb-stick.vmdk \
     -rawdisk ./my-virtual-usb-stick.img
```

then Start the virtual machine, download the Linux iso file and use mkusb with the virtual usb drive.

Once done, stop the virtual machine and quit virtualbox.

Then you can dd your image to a real usb stick (Replace the X with your drive letter):

```
dd if=./my-virtual-usb-stick.img of=/dev/sdX bs=4M status=progress
```

Reboot with your usb stick, and it works !

Comment: +1; Thanks for sharing the details of your solution :-) After 2 days you can 'accept' your own answer by clicking the tick mark. That way you will show other users, that your question has a useful answer :-)

Comment: By the way, please notice that you can use mkusb instead of `dd` to make the final cloning to a USB stick safer. mkusb can clone directly from image files and also from compressed image files (compressed by `gzip` and `xz`), so `file.img`, `file.img.gz` and `file.img.xz`